# Java reading file into memory and how not to blow up memory

Tags: java, file, memory

I'm a bit of a newbie in Java and I trying to perform a MAC calculation on a file.
Now since the size of the file is not known at runtime, I can't just load all of the file in to memory. So I wrote the code so it would read in bits (4k in this case).
The issue I'm having is I tried loading the entire file into memory to see if both methods produce the same hash. However they seem to be producing different hashes

Here's the bit by bit code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sbs.dat");
byte[] file = new byte[4096];
m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
int i=fis.read(file);
m.init(key);
while (i != -1)
{
    m.update(file);
    i=fis.read(file);
}
mac = m.doFinal();
```

And here's the all at once approach:

```
File f = new File("sbs.dat");
long size = f.length();
byte[] file = new byte[(int) size];
fis.read(file);
m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
m.init(key);
m.update(file);
mac = m.doFinal();
```

Shouldn't they both produce the same hash?

The question however is more generic. Is the 1st code the correct way of loading a file into memory into pieces and perform whatever we want to do inside the while cycle? (socket send, cipher a file, etc...).
This question is useful because every tutorial I've seen just loads everything at once...

Update: Working :-D. Will this approach work properly sending a file in pieces through a socket?

Answer (score 5):

No. You have no guarantee that in `fis.read(file)` will read `file.length` bytes. This is why `read()` is returning an int to tell you how many bytes it has actually read.

You should instead do this:

```
m.init(key);
int i=fis.read(file);

while (i != -1)
{
    m.update(file, 0, i);
    i=fis.read(file);
}
```

taking advantage of [Mac.update(byte[] data, int offset, int len)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html#update%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method that allows you to specify length of actual data in in byte[] array.

Comment: Doh. I feel like an idiot, I completely forgot that there's 3 update methods in the Mac classes .Nevertheless, I still would have lost hours around something simple. Gonna try it out, but it sounds right.

Answer (score 4):

The `read` function will not necessarily fill up your entire array. So, you need to check how many bytes were returning from the `read` function, and only use that many bytes of your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Jason LeBrun says - The read method will not always read the specified amount of bytes. For example: What do you think will happen if the file does not contain a multiple of 4096 bytes?

I would go for something like this:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
        Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        m.init(key);

        int n;
        while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            m.update(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        byte[] mac = m.doFinal();
```